# Copy to clipboard body of bootstrap modal that is table from js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a modal that generates a table that gets called from js, I want to copy that table ("table") to the users clipboard. I know there is a previous answer that solves this but that is for a text input. That solution was not working for me. I am very new to JS, sorry for the ignorance. Any help would be appreciated.

html

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div id="table">
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <a href="#" id="copy" data-clipboard-target="#copy-input" class="btn btn-default">Copy input 
  content to clipboard</a>
  <a href="link.com" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" aria- 
  pressed="true">Done</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
  console.log('a', Clipboard, $('#copy'), $("#copy-input").val());
  var clipboard = new Clipboard('#copy')
});
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a few ways of doing it, but this is the way I've done

[W3 Example table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)
[W3 copy to keyboard](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp)

1. Grab the table you want to extract the data for (`getElementById`)
2. Loop over the `.rows` data
3. As you go over the row, look for the `.innerText` of each row's `.children` (cell)
4. Convert to a string, since the clipboard will only accept strings

You may have to modify this a little if you want the result formatted a certain way, but that will depend an your usage and table structure...

```js
const copyTable = () => {
  const tableData = document.getElementById("table")
  const data = [...tableData.rows].map(row => [...row.children].map(cell => cell.innerText))
  console.log("result:", data);
  
  const stringData = data.toString()
  
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(stringData);
  console.log(stringData)
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" onclick="copyTable()">copy</button>
```